# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20-Mar-2013" jar executed through batch from php

Tags: java, php, batch-file

I am executing a batch file from php which executes java jar file. when i run the command normally it runs fine but when i execute it through php. it gives the above error.

can any one help?

Java:

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

        //get current date time
        //tdt = new java.util.Date();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            tdt= sdf.parse(startdate);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReportExporter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

PHP:

```
    $command ="cmd /c ".EXPORT_BATCH_PATH." ".$fromdate." ".$todate." &";
    echo $command;
    $result = system($command, $output);
```

OR:

```
    $command ="cmd /c ".EXPORT_BATCH_PATH." ".$fromdate." ".$todate." &";
    echo $command;
    $result = exec($command, $output);
```

When i run the above echo $command value manually, it runs properly. but through php execution giving error.

My PHP script contains this line;

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');?>
```

Is there any problem with text encoding??

Please look at the accepted answere.. The line below solved my problem;

```
    java -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar c:\Progra~1\MyApplication\MyApplication.jar -exportfromto %1 %2
```

Comment: Which error does it print?

Comment: Are you sure your php command is passing the proper date? I mean, without quotation marks or other symbols.

Comment: yeah i executed the output of $command manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SimpleDateFormat` you construct uses `dd-MMM-yyyy` as the date format. This requires `$fromdate` and `$todate` to be text strings formatted in the same convention.

If you print them in some manner that is locale-aware, chances are that the parse will fail. Your PHP script should explicitely format dates via [`strftime("%d-%b-%Y")`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php). You'll also want PHP and the Java program to use the same locale, since `Mar` is the abbreviated form for *March*, in English locale (also Italian for example, but this string is definitely locale dependent). You pass a `Locale` object to the `SimpleDateFormat` [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29) on the Java side, and [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) as the PHP couterpart.

By the way, when calling external program, always remember [to escape input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to avoid whitespace and other special chars (this may not be your case, but it's a useful general advice because it's often forgotten and leads to unexpected bugs)

Comment: let me try..
is this problem related to character encoding.

Comment: It may be related to character encoding, too

Comment: how to handle character encoding?

Comment: java -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar C:\Progra~1\MyApplication\MyApplication.jar -exportfromto %1 %2

Comment: To make Java use the same locale as PHP, get the locale in the script via `setlocale(LC_ALL, 0)` and set an environment variable before invoking Java with `putenv('LANG=$locale')`